# For a discord.py slash command that iterates the bot asnwer, how can I make it not show that "Tap to see attachment" above the messages?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord.py command that makes feeds of memes, but when I use the command, all the images sent by the bot with exception of the first one have a "tap to see attachment" as if they were a response to the first image, is it possible to make it not appear? If so, how?

```
@bot.hybrid_command(name = "command", with_app_command = True, description = "description")  
async def test1(ctx, number: int):
        
        i = 0
        while i < number:         
            await ctx.send("Message")
            i = i+1
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? We can make guesses about your code but it would be better if you provided your code so we can have a look at it.

Comment: @Esloman, I don't have access to my complete code rn, and it's really big, but I did a small version of it, it's edited on the post. Basically on this version the second, third, fourth bot responses will all "mention" the first. In this case this mention will contain the message content, "Message", but on the original command, that sends images, instead of text messages, it appears the "tap to see attachment"

Answer (score 0):

[`ctx.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.send) will either try to respond to the interaction, followups to the response if a response has been given, or just send if the interaction has expired. I believe the behaviour you're seeing is expected.

If you change your `ctx.send` to [`ctx.channel.send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context.channel) then that should act like a more regular `send`.

We can also add a `defer` to prevent discord saying we didn't respond whilst we sent lots of messages, and then use `ctx.send` at the end to finally respond and tell the user we're done. Using `ephemeral=True` means that we only send the message to the user that initiated the command.

```py
async def test1(ctx, number: int):
    # defer the interaction to prevent "bot didn't respond" messages
    await ctx.defer(ephemeral=True)

    # do the rest of your code here

    # once you're done sending lots of messages

    await ctx.send("Finished meme feed", ephemeral=True)
```

Comment: I tried that before, it actually sends the messages like I want, but for some reason it also appears a "The bot didn't respond" message

Comment: Yup, so the "bot didn't respond" will be because you do need to respond to the interaction in some way shape or form or discord will put that automatically. I'll update my post with a suggestion.